# Remove all ANSI colors/styles from strings

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, ansi-escape

I [use a library](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/couleurs) that adds ANSI colors / styles to strings. For example:

```
> "Hello World".rgb(255, 255, 255)
'\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m'
> "Hello World".rgb(255, 255, 255).bold()
'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'
```

When I do:

```
console.log('\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m')
```

a `"Hello World"` white and bold message will be output.

Having a string like `'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'` how can these elements be removed?

```
foo('\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m') //=> "Hello World"
```

Maybe a good regular expression? Or is there any built-in feature?

---

The work around I was thinking was to create  child process:

```
require("child_process")
 .exec("node -pe \"console.error('\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m')\""
 , function (err, stderr, stdout) { console.log(stdout);
 });
```

But the output is the same...

Comment: You should use [chalk](http://github.com/chalk/chalk). It checks for colors being enabled or not and will automatically strip ANSI codes from your text.

Comment: @Qix It's not about styling, it's about *unstyling* -- removing the ANSI styles from strings. For coloring, I use [`couleurs`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-couleurs) and for unstyling I use [`ansi-parser`](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/node-ansi-parser). Hope it's now clearer.

Comment: `I use a library that adds ANSI colors / styles to strings` And I'm saying by using chalk, you can remove those codes automatically if you so choose (i.e. you can style *and* automatically remove).

Comment: @Qix Ah, I've got it. I thought `chalk` is only for coloring. From what I see, [`strip-ansi`](https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi) is used for this, and you are one of the contributors. :-) Nice!

Comment: I am now; wasn't when I originally posted haha. Came back to update the regex with the one I wrote for [`ansi-regex`](https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex).

Comment: @Qix You could update your answer including the `strip-ansi` package. I always liked tiny and cute npm packages. :)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The [regex you *should* be using](https://github.com/chalk/ansi-regex/blob/master/index.js#L3) is

```
/[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g
```

This matches most of the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), beyond just colors, including the extended VT100 codes, archaic/proprietary printer codes, etc.

Note that the `\u001b` in the above regex may not work for your particular library (even though it should); check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153308/best-ansi-escape-beginning/28934977#28934977) to a similar question regarding acceptable escape characters if it doesn't.

If you don't like regexes, you can always use the [`strip-ansi`](https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi) package.

---

For instance, the string `jumpUpAndRed` below contains ANSI codes for jumping to the previous line, writing some red text, and then going back to the beginning of the next line - of which require suffixes other than `m`.

```js
var jumpUpAndRed = "\x1b[F\x1b[31;1mHello, there!\x1b[m\x1b[E";
var justText = jumpUpAndRed.replace(
    /[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g, '');
console.log(justText);
```

Comment: Full Disclosure: I'm a maintainer of the chalk projects mentioned above

Comment: I'd vote for `stripcolorcodes` lib.

Comment: It hasn't been updated in 11 years. Further the better approach is simply not to emit control codes at all unless the output is probably a TTY.

Answer (score 16):

The escape character is `\u001b`, and the sequence from `[` until first `m` is encountered is the styling. You just need to remove that. So, replace globally using the following pattern:

```
/\u001b\[.*?m/g
```

Thus,

```
'\u001b[1m\u001b[38;5;231mHello World\u001b[0m\u001b[22m'.replace(/\u001b\[.*?m/g, '')
```

Answer (score 4):

The colors are like **ESC[39m** format, the shortest regexp is for it the **/\u001b[^m]*?m/g**

Where **\u001b** is the **ESC** character,
**[^m]*?** is any character(s) till **m** (not greedy pattern),
the **m** itself, and **/g** for global (all) replace.

Example:

```
    var line="\x1B[90m2021-02-03 09:35:50.323\x1B[39m\t\x1B[97mFinding: \x1B[39m\x1B[97m»\x1B[39m\x1B[33m42125121242\x1B[39m\x1B[97m«\x1B[39m\x1B[0m\x1B[0m\t\x1B[92mOK\x1B[39m";
    
    console.log(line.replace(/\u001b[^m]*?m/g,""));
// ->  2021-02-03 09:35:50.323 Finding: »42125121242«  OK ( without colors )
    console.log(line);
// -> 2021-02-03 09:35:50.323 Finding: »42125121242«  OK ( colored )
```