# Basic JavaScript string equality failing in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-print

I have this gulp task

```
gulp.src([`../../**/*.js`].concat(dontCheck.map(p => '!../../' + p)))
    .pipe(gulpPrint(path => {
        let adjusted = path.replace('..\\..\\', '').replace(/\\/g, '/');

        let target = 'account/account.js';
        if (adjusted == target){
            console.log('FOUND');
        } else {
            console.log('NOT FOUND', '|' + target + '|', '|' + adjusted + '|', String(target) == String(adjusted), typeof target, typeof adjusted);
        }
```

And I'm getting this maddening output

[image]

Why aren't those strings matching?  Does `adjusted` have a different unicode encoding?  If so how do I reconcile it?

Comment: Unless you did something fancy with console.log output, it appears that `adjusted` is wrapped in a color control sequence e.g. `\e[31m`. This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29497680/693275

Comment: @RobM.  Ah - that makes sense. I spotted the coloring - foolish of me not to have put 2 and 2 together.  Post an answer so I can accept?

Comment: Glad that worked for you, answer added :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you did something to highlight the console.log output for us, it appears that `adjusted` is wrapped in a color control sequence e.g. `\e[31m`.

[This answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29497680/693275), which provides this regex to replace control sequences:

```
/[\u001b\u009b][[()#;?]*(?:[0-9]{1,4}(?:;[0-9]{0,4})*)?[0-9A-ORZcf-nqry=><]/g
```