# Escaping color strings with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to escape the strings in this sequence

```
[0m[ERROR] [1585551547.349979]: Failed to create bragfiles/downtimer/fight100/2020-03-27. Error: 550 Create directory operation failed.
```

```
[ERROR] [1585551547.349979]: Failed to create bragfiles/downtimer/fight100/2020-03-27. Error: 550 Create directory operation failed.
```

and

```
[32m[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:50.607198] TaskManager.poll: system has no current task.[0m
```

```
[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:50.607198] TaskManager.poll: system has no current task.
```

Plus the occasional double symbol

```
"[0m[32m[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:34.695268] Polling for updates from the server for fight100...[0m"
```

```
"[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:34.695268] Polling for updates from the server for fight100..."
```

---

I've come across this before but it doesn't seem to be correct in my case:

1. [How can I remove the ANSI escape sequences from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693701/how-can-i-remove-the-ansi-escape-sequences-from-a-string-in-python)
2. [Remove all ANSI colors/styles from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245716/remove-all-ansi-colors-styles-from-strings)

---

I've been trying various variations of `\x1B(?:[@-Z\\-_]|\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~])` but I don't think that fits the bill

But none of the regexes I've tried so far seem to be generic enough

Comment: Do you want to remove `[0m` and `[32m`? `text = text.replace('[0m','').replace('[32m','')`?

Comment: More that I want to do it for all color codes in the beginning of lines.  Black        0;30     Dark Gray     1;30
 Red          0;31     Light Red     1;31
 Green        0;32     Light Green   1;32
 Brown/Orange 0;33     Yellow        1;33
 Blue         0;34     Light Blue    1;34
 Purple       0;35     Light Purple  1;35
 Cyan         0;36     Light Cyan    1;36
 Light Gray   0;37     White         1;37

Comment: Is the color escape sequence Always followed by a `'[TEXT]` sequence? Can the string be reliably split so the color escape sequence will be at the **start** of the resultant strings? Is the color sequence either at the start of the string OR preceded by a period? Have you considered making multiple passes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(One or two (color escape sequences)) followed by (uppercase alpha characters enclosed in square brackets)(positive look ahead)

```
pat = r'''((\[\d+m){1,2})(?=\[[A-Z]+\])'''
```

Works with this string:

```
s = '''[0m[ERROR] [1585551547.349979]: xyz xyz.
[0m[32m[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:34.695268] hjk hjk.[0m[32m[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:34.695268] foo bar foo'''
```

The positive lookahead prevents that last bit from being captured.

---

```
>>> print(re.sub(pat,'',s))
[ERROR] [1585551547.349979]: xyz xyz.
[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:34.695268] hjk hjk.[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:34.695268] foo bar foo
>>>
```

---

If you need to remove sequences specifying foreground **and** background colors like

```
[2m[93m[0m[32m[INFO] [2020-03-29 23:58:34.695268] foo bar foo
```

use `pat = r'''((\[\d+m){1,})(?=\[[A-Z]+\])'''` for (one or more) instead of (one or two).

---

If there is **also** stuff like this

```
[0m[1;37m[ERROR] [1585551547.349979]: xyz xyz.
[0m[1;37m[0;32m[ERROR] [1585551547.349979]: xyz xyz.
```

use `pat = r'''(\[([01];)?\d+m){1,}(?=\[[A-Z]+\])'''`

---

Some of your example strings showed color sequences *in the middle* of the string and you desired output showed them being replaced - contrary to your comment

> all color codes in the beginning of lines.

These patterns **will** remove the sequence from the *middle* of a *string*.