# render GitLab job log content

Tags: javascript, swift

Via GitLab log API [/projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/trace](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-log-file), I got the log content like below:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 14.10.0~beta.50.g1f2fe53e (1f2fe53e)[0;m
[0K  on blue-5.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default -AzERasQ[0;m
section_start:1652284543:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "docker+machine" executor[0;m[0;m
[0KUsing Docker executor with image ruby:2.5 ...[0;m
```

and the finial render result should be like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6abVe.png)

my question is:

what kind of this log?

how to read or render it use javascript or swift?  has any library?

Comment: It's using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947742/how-to-change-the-output-color-of-echo-in-linux It's unclear where you need to "render" them, if they accept coloring text, if so, what's the protocol, if not, you might need to remove the coloring tags...

Comment: @Larme thank you, do not need the color, Just need to remove some leading and trailing characters, `[OK` `[36;1m`  `[0;m`, have any idea ?

Comment: Now that you have the name of the tags (ansi color), a quick search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245716/remove-all-ansi-colors-styles-from-strings